# svg file don't show in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, svg, file-upload

I want to upload an svg file to a WordPress site but unfortunately, after uploading to the server, this file turns into an empty svg file with a size of 22 bytes, and there is no code or script in the uploaded file.

I also used plugins like safe svg, but it didn't work.  Can anyone guide me to solve this problem?

Comment: WordPress doesn't handle SVG files correctly without a plugin. You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.

Comment: Are you uploading to the media gallery or another way?

Comment: I test it from media gallery and elementor.